# The texture inside cylinder doesn't change the height

Tags: three.js

I'm trying increase the height of panorama, but after certain number it stops to stretch and I'm getting weird edges instead.

```
var bg = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(backgroundTexture);

var bgBox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(950, 950, 600, 50, 50, true), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
         map: bg,
         side: THREE.BackSide
     }));
```

This is how it looks with height 600: [image]

And this is how it looks when the height is greater than 600:
[image]

Please halp! :)

Comment: you could try to increase the segments?!

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you need increase [Camera frustum far plane](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera) - it must be greater than the height and radius of the cylinder.

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (
    40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2800
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wn18avym/4/ VS http://jsfiddle.net/wn18avym/5/

Comment: my settings for camera: `camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (
    40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);` so I guess it is not a solution. But I will try to play with these values.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! Just needed to increase the size of skyBox, that I completely forgot about! Thanks everybody!